# Can we watch Full HD 1080p content on Netflix for Ubuntu?

Tags: netflix

Because all I see is the 720p content while the same movies and series on Windows 10 shows full HD 1080p.

Answer (score 2):

No, per its policy Netflix only streams Full-HD videos to applications with a content decryption module meeting their requirements and neither Chrome nor Firefox is among them and the native client has been discontinued.

[Source](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742)